# Texts component beside each in Flatlist react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have an array every item in the array have a text and button URL I want to add this texts beside each other 
Using flatlist this is my code

```
<FlatList 
       data={data.ayahs}
       keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
       numColumns= '10'
       columnWrapperStyle={{ flexWrap: 'wrap', flex: 1}}
       renderItem={this._renderItem.bind(this)}
       contentContainerStyle= {{justifyContent: 'center'}}
 />
```

Actual behavior

[image: output]

Expected behavior all texts beside each other

[image]

It's possible to do that with flatlist?

Comment: contentContainerStyle= {{justifyContent: 'center', alignItems:'center'}}

Comment: nothing change I am asking about, all lines be filled by texts not to center the text

Comment: What you want is not possible with FlatList

Comment: @dentemm okay how can achieve this behavior without flatlist if you have any idea?

Comment: Is it not possible to simple concatenate the strings before displaying them?

Comment: every string have a touchable property if I concatenate strings I will lose the ability to do this

Comment: Have you found any solution to this problem? I am also creating a Quran-reading app with react native and I can't display ayah on the same line.