# Render inline elements in FlatList in react native

Tags: react-native, stylesheet, react-native-flatlist

Hi there i am trying to render some texts beside each other in flatlist, i want to make the text occupy all the available space to the previous row like using display inline in css, i can’t do that in flatlist

I want to render text like in this photo

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLLdr.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested `Text` components:

```js
<Text> text 1 <Text> text2 </Text> </Text>
```

I have used this technique with `map` and its working al hamdolilah:

here the [snack example](https://snack.expo.io/BEgzIDj!T)

Comment: i want to render them in flatlist

Comment: [see that to understand what i mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50637398/texts-component-beside-each-in-flatlist-react-native)

Comment: i using scrollToIndex in flatlist, it can't be done with map this is the issues with me.